# Scroll with navigation bar - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, undefined

I'm getting an error in console.log of my website saying

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

If anyone can take a look at my code i've already got and give me a hand on finding the problem.

**Current Code:**

**HTML (Navigation bar)**

```
<!-- Navigation buttons -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Solutions</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#features">Featured</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#customers">Customers</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#meet-team">Team</a></li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li> 
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#get-in-touch">Contact</a></li>                        
     </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript and JQuery**

```
// Navigation Scroll
$(window).scroll(function(event)
{
    Scroll();
});

$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function()
{
    $('html, body').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});

// User define function
function Scroll()
{
    var contentTop = [];
    var contentBottom = [];
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var rangeTop = 200;
    var rangeBottom = 500;
    $('.navbar-collapse').find('.scroll a').each(function()
    {
        contentTop.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
        contentBottom.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + $($(this).attr('href')).height());
    })
    $.each(contentTop, function(i)
    {
        if (winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop)
        {
            $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll').removeClass('active').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: by doing this `$($(this).attr('href'))` you are looking for an `id`. E.g `$('#home')`. are they all present in the page?

Comment: is this your complete HTML? do you have these hashes `#services`, `#features` etc set as `id` on different elements where you want to scroll to?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida You was correct :) Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake!

Comment: What is the template used ? please!

Comment: @chelo_c I've created my own template

Comment: can I download?

Comment: @chelo_c - Send me an email to chrisbeckett13@yahoo.co.uk and i'll respond to you with the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `this.hash` as a selector, the meaning is, as example

```
$( '#about' );
```

This is an id selector. But you have no element with `id="about"`, so no element is selected.

Two possible solutions: or you give set id's on all needed elements, or you use an attribute selector:

```
$('[href="' + this.hash + '"]')
```

Comment: Yeh I'm missing an element with ID to be selected